# Using perl to add lines containing only one string to previous line

Tags: perl

I have a file of names of this kind:

> Josée Maria
>   Sanchez
>   Marco Robert
>   Figaro
>   Max Theodor Schmitz
>   John Smith
>   Maria Catharina Luise
>   Armino

and I want to add each line containing one single string (only one name) to the previous line:

> Josée Maria Sanchez
>   Marco Robert Figaro
>   Max Theodor Schmitz
>   John Smith
>   Maria Catharina Luise Armino

Is there a good one-liner using perl?

Comment: Why do you tag this question as `bash` and you actually ask for perl code?

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n(\S+)$/ $1/mg'
```

Untested, but the idea is to slurp the whole file into a string, then replace  by spaces all newlines that precede a single-word line.